# C: How to print fahrenheit to celsius table in float values

Tags: c

I'm writing a function in C to print a table of fahrenheit to celsius table. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//code for temprature coversion written in a function

main(){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 201; i = i + 20){
        printf("%d %d\n", i, celsius(i));

    }
    return 0;
}


int celsius(int fahr){

    int i, n, p;

    n = 10;

    p = ((5 * (fahr - 32)) / 9);

    return p;

}
```

---

Output:

```
0 -17
20 -6
40 4
60 15
80 26
100 37
120 48
140 60
160 71
180 82
200 93
```

The output only contains integers and no float values. How do I get it to print float values?

Comment: By using `float` instead of `int` and `%f` instead of `%d` in the printf format string.

Comment: I already tried it but it started outputting all values as **0.00** .

Comment: "How do I get it to print float values?" --> use FP variables, argument/return types, math and print specifiers.

Comment: If you tried this, you should show us _that_ code and not the code that uses `int` which will obviously not using floating point math.

Comment: Alright I'll update the question

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 201; i = i + 20){printf("%d %f\n", i, (5*i)/9.0);}`

Comment: I tried the suggestions but the following error is thrown on my ubuntu 18.04 ```dr115f.c:16:7: error: conflicting types for ‘celsius’
 float celsius(int fahr){
      
dr115f.c:9:30: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘celsius’ was here
         printf("%d %f\n", i, celsius(i));
```

Comment: Just a remark: currently `float` is not used very often anymore. `double` is used instead.

Comment: You should be using a compiler that expects a return type on `main()` — one which accepts C99 or later.  You should write `int main(void)` for preference, when you do not use the command line arguments.]

Comment: Jonathon, I'm using **gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0** , is that recommended for beginners? What are the alternatives?

Comment: GCC 7 should be complaining about the absence of `int` on `main()`.  Are you ignoring compiler warnings?  Make sure you use something like `gcc -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror` — I'd add a few more but that's a good starting point.  With GCC 5 or later, you should get warnings like `main.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]` — `1 | main() { return 0; }` — even with the basic `gcc -c main.c`.  (I tested with 9.2.0, then 8.2.0, and then switched machines to where I have 7.2.0 — I don't seem to have 7.4.0 immediately on hand; all gave the same message.)

Comment: @Jonathon ty, highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here: Your `celsius` method returns an integer. You'll want it to return a float:

`int celsius(int fahr)` to `float celsius(int fahr)`

C also uses integer division, so unless you tell it otherwise, it will always return an integer. We can fix this by dividing by `9.0` instead of `9` to tell the code we don't want an integer back. We can also clean this function to one line.

```
float celsius(int fahr){
    return ((5 * (fahr - 32)) / 9.0);
}
```

In your `printf` in `main`, the `%d` is the format specifier for an integer. If you want to print a float, you need to use the float format specifier of `%f`. Lets also tell it to print to 1 decimal spot by using the specifier `%.1f`

```
printf("%d %.1f\n", i, celsius(i));
```

with these changes, the code looks like:

```
float celsius(int fahr){
    return ((5 * (fahr - 32)) / 9.0);
}

main(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 201; i = i + 20){
        printf("%d %.1f\n", i, celsius(i));

    }
    return 0;
}
```

now we get the output

```
0 -17.8                                                                                                                                                                              
20 -6.7                                                                                                                                                                              
40 4.4                                                                                                                                                                               
60 15.6                                                                                                                                                                              
80 26.7                                                                                                                                                                              
100 37.8                                                                                                                                                                             
120 48.9                                                                                                                                                                             
140 60.0                                                                                                                                                                             
160 71.1                                                                                                                                                                             
180 82.2                                                                                                                                                                             
200 93.3
```

Or a more compact solution like @Selbie suggested in the comments, we can clean this up to

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 201; i = i + 20){
  printf("%3d %5.1f\n", i, (5*i)/9.0);
}
```

Comment: Writing ```float celsius(int fahr){
    return ((5 * (fahr - 32)) / 9.0);
}``` before the ```main()``` function helped.

Comment: It would be cleaner still with `printf("%3d %5.1f\n", …)`.

Comment: agreed @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1):

1.Function should return float

2.Printf format should be float format

```
#include <stdio.h>

//code for temprature coversion written in a function
float celsius(int fahr){
   return ((5 * (fahr - 32.0)) / 9);
}

int main()
{
   int i;    
   for (i = 0; i < 201; i = i + 20){
      printf("%3d %5.1f\n", i, celsius(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but the output on Ubuntu 18.04 was ```dr115f.c: At top level:
dr115f.c:16:7: error: conflicting types for ‘celsius’
 float celsius(int fahr){
       ^~~~~~~
dr115f.c:9:32: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘celsius’ was here
         printf("%d %.2f\n", i, celsius(i));
```

Comment: @Ayush You need to put the funciton definition or prototype before `main()`. Otherwise it gives it a default declaration and complains when the definition doesn't match.